# Log to level FINEST in Spring Boot using JDK

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I am using a Spring Boot application where the application.properties is setting the root logging level to TRACE.

I want this to translate to log level FINEST when I make calls to `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient` for debugging purposes, but so far it only logs at the INFO level.

I was able to get the FINEST logging to work by setting the VM option: `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/awgtek/IdeaProjects/Projects/awgtek-api/src/main/resources/logging.properties` in which it is configured as:

```
sun.level = FINEST
```

However, I can't use this method for the deployment. I would need to get the Spring Boot logging mechanism to control the JDK logging. If it helps here are the libraries included:

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.29:compile
```

I also tried adding the following to the Spring Boot Application main method:

```
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

But it did not enable FINEST level logging in the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

I found that replacing `log4j-slf4j-impl` and allow the default Spring Boot logback implementation (remove any exclusions) fixed the issue; i.e. I can control the logging level of `HttpsClient` in application.properties by setting `logging.level.sun.net=TRACE` which enables Java util logging up to level `FINEST`.

Current solution, remove:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```